# How can I tell when my file system was last fsck-ed at all?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, disk, fsck, e2fsck

I know of [various](https://serverfault.com/questions/562116/last-time-a-filesystem-was-checked) ways in which to check when the last fsck occurred on a file system. e.g.

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1 | grep 'Mount count' -A3
dumpe2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Mount count:              74
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Dec 11 21:37:56 2014
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
```

This updates for automatic, fstab-initiated fscks. However, it doesn't seem to take into account manual fscks.

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
<VOLUME_NAME>: clean, 1066411/183140352 files, 572576302/732557824 blocks
$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1 | grep 'Mount count' -A3
dumpe2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Mount count:              74
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Dec 11 21:37:56 2014
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
```

Is there a way to either update this value, or to find the *real* last time fsck was run? This is an ext4 volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the partition is in clean state, there is no actual `fsck` run, which is why the date isn't updated.

If you want to force it, the `-f` option does just that: `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`.